# My UI text not being updating whereas Hook is being updating in react-native?

Tags: react-native, hook

Hello Folks I am using react hook to update my UI when value get change, but I am facing one issue.

This is my code :-

```
  {showAvailableBalance ? (
    <GradientText
    inputWidth={dynamicTextWidth(userBalance, 32)}
    inputHeight={44}
    maskedStyle={styles.flex0}
    text={userBalance || '0'}
    textSystem={'number-large'}
    textAlign={'center'}
  />
) : (
  <Text
    text={parseFloat(
      parseFloat(user?.balance) + onChainBalance,
    ).toFixed(2)}
    textSystem={'number-large'}
    color={Colors.GRAY3}
    style={{ marginLeft: 8 }}
  />
)}
```

To show user balance I have used `userBalance` hook and here I am updating this hook.

```
const [userBalance, setUserBalance] = useState(user?.balance);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('The user updated balance is = ', user?.balance);
    setUserBalance(user?.balance);
  }, [user?.balance]);
```

However this useEffect run when `user.balance` get update but my UI text not being change.

What I am doing wrong can anyone please sugggest me ?

Comment: when you are set ```showAvailableBalance ```? can you please show.

Comment: Yeah this is on specific button click, like when I click on that button then it will set false and other balance will show , and again if click on same button the it will set to true and user balance will show

Comment: And when user balance update `showAvailableBalance` this hook not getting update

Comment: Then you have to add ```showAvailableBalance``` in useEffect dependency.

Comment: show an activity indicator(loader) not the best solution but it will work for sure.

Answer (score 1):

==> Check below code and let me know.

const [userBalance, setUserBalance] = useState(user?.balance);

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('The user updated balance is = ', user?.balance);
    setUserBalance(user?.balance);
  }, [showAvailableBalance,user?.balance]);
```

Comment: Not working, it will only work when I update `showAvailableBalance`, but in my case I have to reflect change on balance update

Comment: i have edited my answer check it and let me know.

Comment: Yeah tried already not working

Comment: share your all the code so i can better understand.

Comment: Then you have problems in another part of the code.

Comment: When I toggle `showAvailableBalance` state in `useEffect` then its work but I don't think this is good solution

Comment: you need to show the component when ```showAvailableBalance``` is true so you need to do this way.

Comment: You mean I have to update `showAvailableBalance` as well when balance get update to show reflect on UI ?

Comment: currently yes or you can change the logic.

Comment: @Pankaj Sonava if my answer is useful to you or solved your problem so you can approve or upvote my answer for motivation.

Comment: I will but still I am looking for better solution

Comment: Redux state solved my problem